# Auto reload in docker compose on code change

Tags: docker

I am starting some services with `docker-compose`:

```
docker-compose up
```

I notice that whenever I make changes to the code base, one of the containers (incidentally the one with the specification `build: ./` in the docker compose file), restarts. I assume this is attributable to `docker-compose`, but I can not find any reference to this fact in the documentation.

Is this really due to `docker-compose`?
Where is this documented?

Comment: It is not docker-compose as such, but most likely the process running in your docker container. What is the entrypoint/cmd of that container and what are you building?

Comment: @MikaelKjær It is `gunicorn` (and it is indeed in autorelad mode). But: why should the process in the container be able to see something that happens in the host? I am not mounting volumes ...

Comment: @MikaelKjær To be more precise: `gunicorn` runs whatever is in the container started from the image built by docker. The image is built by docker, and only changes whenever it is rebuilt (if the sources change). Me updating the code in the development host has no effect in the docker image, *unless* docker takes care of that. `gunicorn` is not aware that I am changing code in the dev host.

Comment: @MikaelKjær correction: I **am** mounting the code volume ... (I hadn't notice this before, sorry)

Comment: I guess that's the answer then. I assume gunicorn is reacting to the mounted code.

Comment: @MikaelKjær Yes, I will accept that as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comments the source code is mounted inside the container and your entrypoint `gunicorn` is looking at that source code and picking up on any changes to it.

This seems like a good development scenario and one of the benefits docker gives.